# How can I improve this piece of code written in Scala?

Tags: scala

I was wondering how can I improve this code to be more readable and fluid. I appreciate your help, Thank You.

```
// filter DWT based on Zone
val dwtListZon = query.zoneOpt match {
  case None => dwtListStn
  case Some(zon) => {
    if (zon.crwStn333 == "all") {
      dwtListStn
    }
    dwtListStn.filter(_.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3)
  }
}
```

I just want to learn how this code ought to be written, in terms of simplicity and readability, in a more declarative (if it could be) fashion.

Answers below show different style of doing same thing which also helps broaden my insight on FP and Scala in general. Thanks for that!

Comment: Maybe a question for codereview.stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This would not be on-topic for Code Review without additional context, as to what this code is supposed to achieve and in what situation(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val dwtListZon = query.zoneOpt filter (_.crwStn333 != "all") map (zon =>
 dwtListStn.filter(_.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3) ) getOrElse dwtListStn
```

or if you want readability

```
val filteredSomething = for(zon <- query.zoneOpt if zon.crwStn333 != "all")
    yield dwtListStn.filter(_.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3)
val dwtListZon = filteredSomething getOrElse dwtListStn
```

Comment: @AS_ actually i made little mistake, check for update

Comment: Coming from the OOP background I am trying to learn more functional way of coding and seeing different ways of doing same thing really, really, helps! Thanks for taking your time in sharing another style of coding. I appreciate it, really.

Comment: @AS_ As OOP-practicioner i have an advice. After you'll find yourself confident with functional composition and scala type system, check out Haskell and dig it untill you understand approaches of whole standard library and lens. Then go back to scala.

Answer (score 5):

You might also consider the `fold` function which is available on `Option`.  It is often a nice syntax for `Options` with a default value, and you get to use the elegant partial function syntax:

```
query.zoneOpt.fold(dwtListStn) { 
    case zon if zon.crwStn333 == "all" => dwtListStn
    case zon => dwtListStn.filter(_.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3)
}
```

Another general strategy here would be to flip the operation around.  All branches of logic return some filtered or unfiltered version of `dwtListStn`, so you could conceive of the whole operation as a `filter`:

```
dwtListStn.filter { dwt => 
    query.zoneOpt match {
        case Some(zone) if zone.crwStn333 == "all" => false
        case Some(zone) => dwt.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3
        case None => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal match can be clear too. Just reverse if condition:

```
query.zoneOpt match {
   case Some(zon) if (zon.crwStn333 != "all") => 
      dwtListStn.filter(_.crwStnAbbr3 == zon.crwStnAbbr3)
   case _ =>
      dwtListStn
}
```